# Laravel factory not returning correct object data

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, factory

I've got the following factory in Laravel 5.7, when invoking it nothing is being returned:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

$factory->define(App\Record::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        "name" => $faker->name,
    ];
});
```

Whereas my model is:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Record extends Model
{
    protected $table = "records";

    protected $fillable = ["name"];

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And I'm invoking the factory here:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

use App;
use App\Product;
use App\Record;
use App\User;

class RecordTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    /** @test */
    public function when_record_page_for_existing_record_is_accessed_then_a_product_is_displayed()
    {
        //$record = factory(App\Record::class)->make();
        $record = factory(App\Record::class)->create();
       echo "\n\n$record->name\n\n";

    }
}
```

when printing

```
$record->name
```

I'm getting nothing, not null, no empty string, just nothing. What seems to be the problem? If I save whatever is generated by the factory into a variable instead of returning it right away I can see that name is being populated, but after returning it nothing happens, it's gone

Comment: Have you tried to dd() the $record variable?

Comment: Yes, it's not a printing issue, the issue is with whatever is trying to print

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This piece of code is the problematic part:

```php
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

You're not passing the attributes to the parent constructor. Eloquent accepts the model's attributes in the constructor, but your overriding constructor doesn't accept them, nor pass them up to the parent.

Change it to this:

```php
function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

BTW, you're overriding Eloquent's constructor, but you're not doing anything in there. Are you sure you actually want to override it?

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot! I was using that constructor since initially my model was inheriting from a Product's model which was inheriting from Model. Since it wasn't working either I decided to remove Product and use just Record inheriting directly from Model. Now that I now the issue I can reverted back to inherit from Product

Comment: Correct, but `$attributes` defaults to an empty array. The method signature is `public function __construct(array $attributes = [])`

Comment: @None is right, it will result to "Too few arguments in __construct" error. The attributes must be optional.

Answer (score 1):

By default `phpunit` won't print your `echo`.

To print it, please use `phpunit -v`

Comment: phpunit does print echo statements. It'll print whatever you specify within the test